# Intellij Idea - ambiguous method call

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I encountered a strange error related to Java using Intellij Idea.

So there is such interface :

```
<T> void save(T aEntity, DbTransaction dbTransaction, Class<T> clazz);
<T> void save(Collection<T> aEntities, DbTransaction dbTransaction, Class<T> clazz);
```

When I try to compile the next code :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void save(Collection<T> aEntities, DbTransaction aDbTransaction) {
    baseDao.save(aEntities, aDbTransaction, getClass((T) aEntities.toArray()[0]));
}
```

I receive the next compilation error :

```
reference to save is ambiguous, both method <T>save(T,DbEntityHelper.DbTransaction,java.lang.Class<T>) in xzc.dao.IBaseDao and method <T>save(java.util.Collection<T>,DbEntityHelper.DbTransaction,java.lang.Class<T>) in xzc.dao.IBaseDao match
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: what is the signature for `getClass()`?

Comment: How `baseDao` declared? Is it parametrized?

Comment: Nope, as you can see from method signature, T is "declared" in the methods signature. The interface isn't parametrized at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two types called `T` and it can't assume they are the same. `T` could be `Collection<T>` in the second method or it could be `T` in the first.

You can use

```
baseDao.<T>save(....
```

or

```
baseDao.<Collection<T>>save(....
```

to make it clear which one it should be.  Making them the `T` same name doesn't help the compiler and may just be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The erased signatures of the two save methods are

```
(Object, DBTransaction, Class)
(Collection, DBTransaction, Class)
```

and the compiler can't decide which one you intended to call.  An explicit cast should help here:

```
baseDao.save((Collection)aEntities, aDbTransaction, getClass((T) aEntities.toArray()[0]));
```

Comment: It doesn't help. The solution with baseDao.<Collection<T>>save works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the type `<T>` explicitely like in the following:

```
baseDao.<Collection<T>>save(aEntities, aDbTransaction, getClass((T) aEntities.toArray()[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I get this sort of error because of type erasure.

Check the other methods in your code to make sure they are all differrent when you remove any of hte type information. If there are two or more the same then this could be your prolem.

For erasure see this on the java trail
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Can you post the rest of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Click where the text is differently colored, and elect to import the specific class for `save()` (using your shortcut key - Mac is Alt-Enter).  Alternatively, you can use the fully-qualified class name to disambiguate between the two different `save()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), those two methods have the same signature.

Briefly, at runtime all type information is erased, so your two methods effectively become:

```
Object void save(Object aEntity, DbTransaction dbTransaction, Class clazz);
Object void save(Collection aEntities, DbTransaction dbTransaction, Class clazz);
```

Because your parameter is a `Collection`, but the `T` of the collection is not necessarily the *same* `T` as the other method, so both methods could match.

Try an explicit cast to either `Collection` or `Object`.

Comment: Really ? How can be T ( Object ) be equivalent to Collection<T> ( Collection ) ?

Comment: @AndreiPodoprigora - collection is an object too, I believe.

Comment: @Vic - but shouldn't the compiler select the most specific method ?

Comment: @AndreiPodoprigora - compiler cannot know for sure. What if you have an Object variable that points to a collection as opposed to Object variable that points to whatever.